# ¿Cómo asignar el resultado de un case_when a todas las filas de un grupo definido con group_by?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Estoy trabajando con la [ENOE](https://www.inegi.org.mx/programas/enoe/15ymas/) y quiero asignar a cada hogar el nivel educativo del "Jefe o jefa de hogar", código 101 en la variables `par_c`. La idea es crear una nueva columna en la que cada fila de un grupo (es decir, para todos los miembros del hogar) se repita el la escolaridad del jefe.

La n real es casi 500k, entonces el ahorro de RAM y el desempeño importan.

Así se ven los datos mínimos:

| id_hogar | par_c | cs_p13_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 101 | Preparatoria o bachillerato |
| 1000 | 201 | Secundaria |
| 1000 | 301 | Preparatoria o bachillerato |
| 1001 | 101 | Preparatoria o bachillerato |
| 1002 | 101 | Profesional |
| 1002 | 201 | Carrera técnica |
| 1002 | 301 | Profesional |
| 1002 | 418 | Profesional |
| 1002 | 408 | Secundaria |
| 1003 | 101 | Maestría |
| 1004 | 101 | Primaria |
| 1005 | 101 | Preparatoria o bachillerato |
| 1005 | 301 | Preparatoria o bachillerato |
| 1005 | 301 | Profesional |

Y así se reproducen:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)  #Para las etiquetas de cs_p13_1, son datos importados de stata 

structure(list(id_hogar = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1001L, 1002L, 
1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1003L, 1004L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L
), par_c = structure(c(101, 201, 301, 101, 101, 201, 301, 418, 
408, 101, 101, 101, 301, 301), format.stata = "%12.0g"), cs_p13_1 = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 8L), .Label = c("Ninguno", 
"Preescolar", "Primaria", "Secundaria", "Preparatoria o bachillerato", 
"Normal", "Carrera técnica", "Profesional", "Maestría", "Doctorado", 
"No Sabe"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")) -> datos
```

La solución que tengo:

```
datos %>% 
  group_by(id_hogar) %>% 
  mutate(escolaridad_jefe = case_when(par_c == 101 ~ cs_p13_1)) %>% 
  fill(escolaridad_jefe, .direction = "downup")
```

Que funciona muy rápido con los datos de ejemplo, pero no me parece óptima. Es muy lento con el caso real porque son 500k filas, condiciones más complejas y, sobre todo, muchas variables las que tengo que crear así. Entonces tengo que hacer un `fill` para cada variable y el código se pone complicado de mantener.

¿Hay alguna manera directa para que el `mutate(case_when))` asigne el valor output a todas las filas del grupo? Por diseño de la encuesta sé a priori que un solo jefe/a por hogar.

`nest()` no es una opción, anidar y desanidar demoran un minuto por operación.

> PD: una solución no tidyverse (base, data.table) es bienvenida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probaría con un `left_join()`

```
datos %>% 
  left_join(datos %>% 
              filter(par_c == 101) %>% 
              select(id_hogar, escolaridad_jefe = cs_p13_1),
            by = "id_hogar")
```

La subconsulta filtra los casos de "Jefe o jefa de hogar" y nos quedamos con su nivel educativo. Finalmente al relacionar por el `id_hogar` todas las filas heredan el nivel del jefe.

En cuanto a la performance, no puedo asegurar nada, pero posiblemente al ser menos "verbos" y más simples, puede que mejore algo el comportamiento.

Comment: Sí, de hecho como tengo muchas condiciones me queda muy bien hacer un tabla para el join con todas las combinaciones e ir directo con el left_join. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Actualizo comentario: en producción 30x más rápido que case_when y la mitad de líneas de código. Lo que se dice una **solución**. Muchísimas gracias!