# Asignar el resultado de un case_when a todas las filas definido por group_by? R

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr, dplyr

Estoy intentando asignar un valor a un grupo en base a los datos de la fila, tengo un `ID` que se repite para varias filas, esas filas tienen valores que cambian, puede ser 1 fila o 10 eso da igual. En función a los valores de una columna especifica `Especie_num`  , quiero agregar un resultado a todo el grupo.

Pongo un ej de mi df

```
    ID         Especie_sp      Especie_num Codigo_final
 1 232A1     Pinus pinaster           26    NA     
 2 232A1     Quercus faginea          44    NA     
 3 232A1     Quercus faginea          44    NA     
 4 232A1     Quercus ilex             45    NA     
 5 232A1     Quercus ilex             45    NA     
 6 233A1     Quercus ilex             45    NA     
 7 233A1     Quercus ilex             45    NA     
 8 233A1     Quercus ilex             45    NA     
 9 235A3E    Quercus ilex             45    NA     
10 235A3E    Quercus ilex             45    NA
```

Como ven en el ID 232A1, tengo el `Especie_num` 26, 44, 45, esa codificación lleva un `Codigo_final` que lo tengo en otra tabla.

Ej al que quiero llegar:

```
    ID         Especie_sp      Especie_num Codigo_final
 1 232A1     Pinus pinaster           26    X     
 2 232A1     Quercus faginea          44    X     
 3 232A1     Quercus faginea          44    X     
 4 232A1     Quercus ilex             45    X     
 5 232A1     Quercus ilex             45    X     
 6 233A1     Quercus ilex             45    X     
 7 233A1     Quercus ilex             45    X     
 8 233A1     Quercus ilex             45    X     
 9 235A3E    Quercus ilex             45    V1    
10 235A3E    Quercus ilex             45    V1
11 239A1     Quercus suber            46    XII
```

Si el valor de la fila dentro del grupo es uno determinado se le asigna el código a todo el grupo, Si ven, en num 45 al estar con otros toma un valor ( en este caso una X), pero si esta solo en el grupo toma otro (V1) y así para muchas categorías que tengo armadas.

Pensé en esto: Agrupo por `ID` y con un `case_when` aplico el resultado a todos (Pongo solo 2  `case_when` para no hacer largo el ejemplo)

```
Datos = data %>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(Codigo_final = case_when(Especie_num == "45" & Especie_num == "44" & Especie_num == "26"  ~ "X",
                        case_when(Especie_num == "45" ~ "V1"))
```

Lo raro es que si pongo mas de una variable, me da `NA`, pero si pongo una sola si obtengo resultado. Sera que el `group_by` no esta funcionando bien?

He pensado tambien en `pivot_wider`,  `nest` para poner en una misma fila todas las variables, pero tampoco me dio resultado

Esta pregunta es bastante similar en cuanto a asignar un valor a todo el grupo, pero no me ha ayudado ya que se basa en un filtro
[¿Cómo asignar el resultado de un case_when a todas las filas de un grupo definido con group_by?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/531139/c%c3%b3mo-asignar-el-resultado-de-un-case-when-a-todas-las-filas-de-un-grupo-definid)

Cual seria el mejor método? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

creo que la mejor forma de usar `case_when` es:

```
data %>% 
# group_by(ID) %>%  # no creo que sea necesario 
mutate(Codigo_final = case_when(
Especie_num == 45 & ID == '235A3E' ~ "V1",
Especie_num == 45 ~ "X",
Especie_num == 44 ~ "X",
Especie_num == 26 ~ "X", 
Especie_num == 46 ~ "XII" 
))
```

Así, puedes obtener el resultado que buscas:

```
       ID          Especie_sp       Especie_num   Codigo_final
       1   232A1  Pinus pinaster          26            X
       2   232A1 Quercus faginea          44            X
       3   232A1 Quercus faginea          44            X
       4   232A1  Quercus ilex            45            X
       5   232A1  Quercus ilex            45            X
       6   232A1  Quercus ilex            45            X
       7   233A1  Quercus ilex            45            X
       8   233A1  Quercus ilex            45            X
       9  235A3E  Quercus ilex            45           V1
       10 235A3E    Quercus ilex          45           V1
       11  239A1   Quercus suber          46          XII
```